# lmer 0-intercept model with binary predictor: Get Cohen's d for difference from zero for both groups

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, effect-size, cohens-d

I have a binary predictor `group = c("negative", "positive")` and this model syntax: `outcome ~ 0 + group + (1|subject) + (1|stimulus)`. In the summary, I receive point estimates for both group means, which is what I want. Now, I want to have a Cohen's d effect size for how much each of both groups *differs from zero*.

I found [this paper](https://psycnet.apa.org/doi/10.1037/xge0000014) by Westfall et al. where they describe how to obtain Cohen's d for the *difference between both groups*. They also mention in the appendix that this procedure does not work for dummy-coded variables. I cannot find any information on whether their approach would be suited to estimate Cohen's d for the difference of each group from zero. Basically, they divide the difference in means from the sum of all the variance in the model (including variance of the coefficient, random intercepts, random slopes (not present in my model), and residual variance).

I applied their formula to my question. Here is what I did:

```
d = coef_groupnegative/sqrt(coef_groupnegative.std^2 + var_subject + var_stimulus + var_residual)
```

And for the confidence intervals, I followed the procedure for one sample effect sizes for regular Cohen's d:

```
ci.upper = d + (1.96 * sqrt(1/n_groupnegative) + ((d^2)/2*n_groupnegative))
ci.lower = d - (1.96 * sqrt(1/n_groupnegative) + ((d^2)/2*n_groupnegative))
```

The results I obtained seem realistic but are they correct? If I calculate Cohen's d in the raw data, the direction of effects is not always the same as the direction of the coefficients, if they are very close to zero. So apparently, it would be wrong to report Cohen's d from raw data together with the results from the mixed model.